# How to get ordered product's color and size in magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, event-observer, product-attribute

I want to get the color and size of ordered product on **sales_order_save_after**

i have write this code

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
$color = $product->getAttributeText('color');
```

config.xml event

```
<events>
    <sales_order_save_after> 
        <observers>
            <Piyush_orderexport_order_save_after>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Piyush_OrderExport_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>exportOrder</method>
            </Piyush_orderexport_order_save_after>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
```

but no value found

Comment: for simple product or configure product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that color and size are product attributes.

to get product attribute you can use below code

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
$size = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$color =  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

for config product use below code

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

foreach( $order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item ) {
    $options = $item->getProductOptions();
    $options = $options['attributes_info'];
}
```

it will give you all product option used for order and option value

output will look

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Color
            [value] => White
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Size
            [value] => XS
        )

)
```

Comment: above code giving value  `<Item_Color>No</Item_Color>`

Comment: if product do not have assign any attribute value it will return "No"

Comment: how can I check that attribute are assign or not ?

Comment: open product in admin and check that product do have assign attribute value

Comment: I checked it and the attribute value is assigned

Comment: Then my code will definitely give you attribute value. I have tested it many time. make sure you are using correct attribute code.

Comment: I am using configurable products. Is that creates problems ?

Comment: check answer again

Comment: it gives me only size not color